# tumblr api not showing all posts

Tags: ruby, json, api, tumblr

I am using the ruby api for retrieving tumblr posts. The api seems to be working, however it limits the response to only a portion of the posts available on the tumblr website. For example, I have three posts tagged as "books", but when I get the json back from the api, the string "books" does not appear anywhere within it.

Here is the code I'm using to call the api:

```
def api
    Tumblr.configure do |config|
     config.consumer_key = "my_consumer_key"
     config.consumer_secret = "my_secret_key"
    end

    client = Tumblr::Client.new(:client => :httpclient)
    render json: client.posts("fmendesl.tumblr.com", :type => "photo", :limit => 10111111)
end
```

I also tried this and had the same error:

```
def api
    require 'net/http'

    url = URI.parse('http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/fmendesl.tumblr.com/posts/photo?api_key=fuiKNFp9vQFvjLNvx4sUwti4Yb5yGutBN4Xh10LXZhhRKjWlV4&tag=')
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.to_s)
    res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
      http.request(req)
    }
    render json: res.body
end
```

Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Could you please post the code you are using so that we have something to work with?

Comment: Just noticed that when I use the second one, I only get 5 posts because that request specifies a tag while the above script does not specify a tag.

Comment: Also the first code block requires the tumblr_client gem. Using that gem with the above code gives me 2015 total posts, which is more than the maximum that Iharby suggested.

Comment: When I removed the tag from the `url` string, it also returned 2015 posts, and none had the tag `books`.